# How do you replace id numbers with names since the columns aren't joined directly?  (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, relational-database

Let's say you have a database with two tables named "clients" and "referrals".

TABLE clients has two columns: "id" and "name".
TABLE referrals also has two columns: "id" and "referred_by"

Both "id" columns are `PRIMARY_KEY`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, `NOT_NULL`

TABLE clients has three rows:

```
1 | Jack  
2 | Frank  
3 | Hank
```

TABLE referrals also has three rows:

```
1 | 0  
2 | 1  
3 | 2
```

Meaning, Jack is client 1 and was referred by no one; Frank is client 2 and was referred by Jack; Hank is client 3 referred by Frank.

The SELECT command I used to display the meaning above was:

```
mysql_query("SELECT clients.id, clients.name, referrals.referred_by FROM clients INNER JOIN referrals ON clients.id=referrals.id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['referred_by'] . "<br>";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
1 Jack 0  
2 Frank 1  
3 Hank 2
```

**Now the real question is:**

How should I modify the code so that it outputs the name of the referrer instead of their id?

Meaning, it should look like this:

```
1 Jack  
2 Frank Jack  
3 Hank Frank
```

Thanks in advance ~

Edit: Make sure to mention how I should update the array as I'm lost on how I should update that whole echo line.

Comment: Why do you need 2 tables for this? One should be enough, with columns: `id, name, referred_by`.

Comment: If I had 2 tables, it would make more sense to have in table `referrals` both the `id` and `referred_by` columns as FOREIGN KEYs to `clients.id`

Comment: And do not even store the `1,0` record. Client `1,Jack` has not been reffered, so no record for him in the `referrrals` table.

Comment: I simplified my real world project to a simple example so that it would be easier for someone to jump in and help.  Also it made it easier for me to learn.  I did try a bunch of different variations but I kept getting errors and after a couple frustrating hours I decided to just post the question on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there - you just need to join back to the clients table a 2nd time to get the referrer name:

```
mysql_query("SELECT clients.id, clients.name, rclients.name as referred_by
FROM clients 
INNER JOIN referrals ON clients.id=referrals.id
LEFT JOIN clients as rclients ON referrals.referred_by = rclients.id");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['referred_by'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What to u mean by Update the array ?

Comment: I dont' know what you're asking for with "updating the array". You were asking how to retrieve the names of the referrer, which the query supplied will do.

Comment: I'm asking how to display what I selected.  Clearly, I'm using this line to display what was selected:

echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['name'] . " " . $row['referred_by'] . "<br>";

I'm simply asking how to update that line so it works.  It's not like copy and pasting your code fixes everything.  In fact, the whole first row doesn't even display.  If I were to copy it, it would only show entries starting after the first client.

Comment: Alright it works except the first row doesn't display I think because the client has no referrer?  Anyway to include the first row?

Comment: @Derek: `INNER JOIN clients as rclients` should be `LEFT JOIN clients as rclients` so `'Jack'` is still shown - and as referred by none (`NULL`)